# Google AdWords Issue: DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED

Tags: google-ads-api

I have created an AdWords Account having a campaign running. I have created a production MCC account. But I have not applied for Basic Level token. It is the  Test Account Access token. 
When execute the GetCampaign program, I get the following error:

```
Request failed due to ApiException. Underlying ApiErrors:
Error 0: QuotaCheckError{apiErrorType=QuotaCheckError, 
errorString=QuotaCheckError.DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED, fieldPath=, 
reason=DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED, trigger=<null>}
```

DO we need to have the Basic Access level token for accessing the API data.
Won't the test token suffice?

Comment: You'll need to have an approved developer token to be able to access any production account, yes.

Comment: thanks @dorian for the clarification. I solved the issue by using the Dev token of Production and OAuth2 credentials of test account

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by using the Dev token of Production and OAuth2 credentials of test account

Comment: What does "test account" mean? how do you make a test account? I already added my MCC account as a Test User in the OAuth Consent Screen.